# Store multiple arrays based on user input

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a function where it allows the user to type in multiple amounts of integers, so if the user wanted to have 3 different storages that hold different integers, the input would look something like this:

```
5 
97 12 31 2 1 //let's say this is held in variable "a"
1 3 284 3 8  // "b"
2 3 482 3 4 // "c"
2 3 4 2 3  // "d"
99 0 2 3 42 // "e"
```

Since we don't know what number the user will input every time, I'm not sure how to create a dynamically allocated array that will create an x amount of arrays every time.. I want to be able to access each index of a, b, c, d, e or however many arrays there are.

So far, this is what I have, but I'm having trouble creating the arrays since it's unpredictable. I'm purposely not using vectors because I don't really get how pointers work so I'm trying to play around with it.

```
int* x;
int length, numbers;
cin >> length;
x = new int[length]

for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, numbers); //this didn't work for me
    x[i] = numbers
}
```

If anything seems unclear, please let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get the first line. It gets 1 integer at a time and since you have 5 integers per line and you entered 5 in the first line you end up getting only the numbers in the first line. `x` in your code is an array of integers and it needs to have enough place for all your integers which in this case is 25. If 5 integer per line is guaranteed then you can assume allocating `5 * length` integer-long place will work. You will also need an inner for loop. 1 `for` to loop through lines and another one to loop through every integer on a line.

Comment: I'm having trouble creating a second for loop. How do i approach this?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        cin >> numbers;
        x[j] = numbers
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using cin like so:

```
int d;
while(cin){
  cin >> d;
  // Do something with d

  if(cin.peek() == '\n'){
    // Create a new row in your dynamic array
  }
}
```

This will grab each digit up to the space.

Another way to achieve this is by using strings with [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) in conjunction with [`string.empty()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/empty/) to get each line, then using [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to split the line up into tokens. Although `getline` only works on strings, `strtok` will split the string up into tokens, which you can then cast to an int (or use atoi).

To store these tokens you will want to use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), since they are dynamic by nature and can easily be resized to fit any need. I would [see this discussion](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/833/) on multi-dimensional vectors.

Comment: I don't seem to follow. getline will grab any text up until a new line. Can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: I did getline, but it only works for strings* sorry. I'll post an example

Comment: Okay I see. I have updated my answer to include additional information.